# Parameter value related issue in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using BIDS to create reports in SSRS.I have added one Parameter PaidMonth and set it's default value to "012013" and deployed the report on report server `(http://localhost/reportserver)` and report is running properly.

Now I changed the PaidMonth parameter value to "032013" in BIDS and deployed the report on the report server.I run the report on report server and found that PaidMonth parameter values has not changed.It's showing it's prevoius value i.e. "012013"

To change the parameter value on report server I have to delete the report from report server and deploy again on report server via BIDS.

Do you have any other quick solution except delete option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting/redeploying the report you can update the server-side default in Report Manager by selecting **Manage** -> **Parameters** for the report, then setting the default as required:

[image]

Still needs some action from a user but is lower impact than deletion.